# Linking a static library in gfortran using preprocessor

Tags: static-libraries, gfortran

I have a library file created in gfortran, how to link it to a host program that uses its procedures using preprocessor (without using the GUI method)
For exemple in Intel Visual fortran this is done by:

```
!DEC$ Objcomment lib: 'library.lib'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/7-ARkC9a0J8), there is no such directive in GCC that allow you linking static libraries. Instead, use the command line:

`gfortran filename.f90 -o filename -L[path] -l[lib]`